# Do I own derivatives of my copy written work? Can I make these open source?

Tags: proprietary-code, derivative-works

Suppose I have a software program I publish under a non-free license that does not give permission to create derivatives, and I own the copyright. Someone decides that despite the copyright they are going to make a derivative of it anyway.

**My question:**

If this happens: Do I own the derivative that the person made? Could I take the derivative and publish it under an open source license?

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't own the derivative that somebody else make of your work.

Creating a derivative requires *permission* from the creator of the original work.  One of the purposes if free culture licenses is to grant anybody this permission up front.  If your work is *not* free (for instance, it is "All Rights Reserved"), then nobody can legally create a derivative of your work.

What you *can* do if somebody goes ahead and make a derivative anyway, is to sue for copyright infringement.  If you win the case, you are eligible for monetary compensation, and the illegal derivative must be removed from the market - but the copyright of the adaptation is *still* owned by the infringer and cannot be transferred to you by any legal decision.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote, but in this case, I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Clearly, someone is of the opinion that this answer is generically "not useful".

Comment: @ArtOfCode. Yeah, that's the generic reason for a downvote (revealed when you hover over the button). But knowing *why* it is "not useful" would allow me to improve on it.

Comment: Good question, and one I can't answer. One Of Those Things.

Comment: If you win, and both sides agree, then a transfer can be a legal remedy, in lue of money. (maybe the other party would have to settle out of court if the court does not recognise this).

Comment: Does this answer apply to any jurisdiction?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul At least, it applies to all Berne jurisdictions, which includes the entire civilized world + USA.